# Java Calendar 31st January issue

Tags: java

I have the following code :-

```
        Calendar calc = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy");
        calc.set(Calendar.YEAR, calc.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1);
        calc.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.NOVEMBER);
        System.out.println("---NOV? : " + sdf.format(calc.getTime()));

        Calendar calc1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calc1.set(Calendar.YEAR, calc1.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1);
        calc1.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER);
        System.out.println("-- DEC : " + sdf.format(calc1.getTime()));
```

The output of the above code is :-

```
> ---NOV? : Dec-2012
> -- DEC : Dec-2012
```

This happens only for 31st january, can someone explain why this might be happening?

Comment: Works fine for me.  Not sure why you're getting that output.

Comment: Maybe interesting similar java.util.Calendar confuce: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605360/a-strange-behavior-from-java-util-calendar-on-february#14605360

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Calendar is set for lenient interpretation, so if you tell it the 31st day of November, well, November only has 30 days, so it rolls over to December 1st.

Comment: I'd love to know where you see him setting the day, since all I see are year and month values being set.

Comment: @Makoto where he lives, ostensibly somewhere east of you and me, "today" is already Jan 31st.  Calendar.getInstance() returns a calendar set to "now" so it comes pre-set to 31 before he changes the month.

Comment: Assumes today's day. I just ran it today, 31st January here ... got same result as OP LOL!

Comment: Use `calc.setLenient(false)` to make it fail on bad date.

Comment: i required only month and year in my case, so didn't really think about the date! thanks

Answer (score 5):

I suspect the first case is rounding "November 31" to "December 1", since you're not changing the day in your calendar.

Comment: I'd love to know where you see him setting the day, since all I see are year and month values being set.

Comment: indeed - that's the problem - he's taking the current day (Jan 31), and setting the month to either November or December - resulting in November 31 or December 31. November 31 doesn't exist, so it becomes December 1.

Comment: Absolutely perfect. I tested the same code on my machine. same output but when I changed my current date to Jan30, it worked fine...! So @Chris you are right.

Comment: didn't realize about the date, required only the month and the year for my scenario. This code had been working fine for the past 2 months and suddenly on the 31st when it all kind of "exploded" I couldn't even think of a reason why!!