# GregorianCalendar time discontinuity between two days

Tags: java

I tried to compare the number of ms between two dates and I have problems with some specific dates.
example for the 2015 february the 1st:

```
System.out.println(new GregorianCalendar(2015, 01, 30, 12, 0, 0).getTimeInMillis());
System.out.println(new GregorianCalendar(2015, 01, 31, 12, 0, 0).getTimeInMillis());
System.out.println(new GregorianCalendar(2015, 02, 01, 12, 0, 0).getTimeInMillis());
```

this returns time in ms which are not ordered chronologically:

```
1425294000000 
1425380400000 
1425207600000
```

I already know how to avoid the problem using another class (DateFormat). But I do not understand the problem.

Comment: You are Comparing Feb 31st with March 1st... check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29 for details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A strange behavior from java.util.Calendar on February](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605360/a-strange-behavior-from-java-util-calendar-on-february)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

31st of February doesn't exist. Month (2nd argument) of the `GregorianCalendar` constructor is a 0-based index. [0-11]

Comment: Indeed, you should use the constants defined in the `Calendar` class to avoid confusion. E.g. `Calendar.FEBRUARY`.

Comment: Even though they provided those constants, I'd regard it as *surprising* that the month parameter (and *only* the month parameter) is zero indexed. [Common sense should have dictated that it be 1-12 instead.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)