# February in Java Calendar

Tags: java, calendar

I have a problem, I think that the result of this block of code should be "February", but the result is "March", what I'm doing wrong?

```
    import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Calendario {

        public static void main(String args[]){
            Locale locale = new Locale("es","MX");
            Calendar calendarTemp = new GregorianCalendar();
            calendarTemp.set(Calendar.MONTH,1);
            String mesTemp = calendarTemp.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, locale);
            System.out.println(mesTemp);

        }

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try that today (i.e. on June 30)?

Comment: Adding to Henry's comment, today is June 30th, setting June 30th to February = Feburary 30th = March

Comment: 30 Feburary = 2 March?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A strange behavior from java.util.Calendar on February](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605360/a-strange-behavior-from-java-util-calendar-on-february)

Comment: @Jesper, May be worth adding that `30 Feb == 2 Mar` on non-leap years only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try using clear before set? Like this:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("es","MX");
Calendar calendarTemp = new GregorianCalendar();
calendarTemp.clear(); //add this line
calendarTemp.set(Calendar.MONTH,1);
```

I tested and the result is "February".

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that February 30 is coming back as March 2.

This duplicate question has the best answer: 
[A strange behavior from java.util.Calendar on February](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605360/a-strange-behavior-from-java-util-calendar-on-february)

Answer (score 3):

It is the 30th of June today, and you never set the day of month in your code, so the 30th is assumed. Since February has fewer than 30 days, it overflows and you end up in March. Try the code below, and notice, that setting the day of month affects what is being displayed:

```
calendarTemp.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
calendarTemp.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

As a side note, it makes code more readable to use constants from the `Calendar` class, eg. `Calendar.FEBRUARY` instead of magic numbers, especially because months are 0-based...

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

To get localized name of a month, call [`Month.getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale))

```
Month.FEBRUARY.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH )
```

## *java.time*

The terribly flawed `Calendar` class is now legacy, supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

To get the current Year, use [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html) class. A time zone ([`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html)) is required because for any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. So around the end/start of the year, the date may be January 1 in Tokyo Japan while simultaneously December 31 in Toledo Ohio US.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
Year year = Year.now( z ) ;
```

To represent February of that year, use [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class. For the month, pass `2` for February — note the sane month numbering, unlike `Calendar` class! More conveniently, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum object, [`Month.FEBRUARY`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html#FEBRUARY).

```
YearMonth februaryThisYear = YearMonth.of ( year.getValue() , Month.FEBRUARY ) ;
```

To get a date in that month, specify day to produce a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate firstOfFebThisYear = februaryThisYear.atDay( 1 ) ;
```

Get the month from a date.

```
Month month = firstOfFebThisYear.getMonth() ;
```

Generate text in localized format.

```
FormatStyle formatStyle = TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE ;  // An enum object.
Locale locale = Locale.GERMANY ; 
String output = month.getDisplayFormat( formatStyle , locale );
```